# Postする際の文字数上限

Tags: java, http, tomcat

jsp+サーブレットでWebアプリ開発を勉強しているのですが
textareaから長い文章（18万字、500kB程）を２つ送信したときに
formからPostしたデータがサーブレット側で受け取れないことがありました。
プログラム側でエラーも発生せずに、textareaから受け取った値はnullとなっています。

アプリケーションサーバーはtomcatを使用しており、maxPostSizeを変更しても結果は変わりませんでした。

textareaに入力する文字数を減らすと問題なく動きます。

原因がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご回答のほどよろしくお願いします。

Comment: `maxPostSize`はどのような値に変更しましたか？変更後のserver.xmlの抜粋を記載してください。

Comment: maxPostSizeの変更後、Tomcatのプロセスを再起動させましたか？

Comment: maxPostSizeは-1にしてTomcatの再起動もしました

Comment: Apacheと連携してTomcatを運用していますか？また、この現象はどのブラウザからのアクセスでも発生しますか？maxPostSizeの制限にかかると500が発生するようなので、maxPostSizeの設定の関係は薄い気がします。

Comment: tomcatを解凍して、saver.xml設定をあまりいじっていないのですが、これだとApacheと連携させていることにはならないのでしょうか？

Comment: Apacheを別途インストールして設定を変更したり、デーモンを起動したりしていないのであれば連携していないと思います。Formタグ部分のソースや利用しているサーバーのOSやブラウザ、tomcatのバージョンなどもう少し詳しく書いていただくと何かわかるかもしれません。

Comment: ということは連携してないことになるようですね  
フォーム部分
<form action="../myapps/Myapp" method="post">
tomcat　apache-tomcat-8.5.24
ブラウザ　IE11
サーバーOS　Linux（Red Hat 4.8.5-11）です

Comment: 他の人が気づきにくいため、環境やフォームのソースについては、質問本文にわかりやすく追記してください。